# Machine Learning Organization/Object-Oriented ML

Tags: machine-learning, project-management

How do you guys organize your ML/data science code and rapidly explore new options? I took an OOP course in college, but I've been at a loss as to how to structure my code.

For example: I have separate data files. Each one can have NaN values imputed in a number of ways: using median, mean, setting to zero, elimination, etc.

Each one ought to be normalized in different ways. Each one can have different dimensionality reduction techniques applied to it, or different clustering methods, each with a dozen different metrics, etc.

That's just the data—then I can have different feature selection methods for each one, I can include different combinations of the differently handled data files, and so on.

At some point, I know that I can't try everything out, and that eventually I'll have experience that guides these decisions easier. But for example, I made a clustering method based off of a paper I read, and I want to try using that instead of my Random Forest to mess with my features, but the way my code is structured, it seems very error-prone and quite a hassle. I want to be able to create something, or think of a new avenue, then easily make a new model and check it out.

I've never really done anything big before, and I am just a terrible organizer in general.